# Drive Letters Usage with the FileSystemObject - VBScript

Tags: scripting, vbscript, filesystemobject

I am migrating from a Win 2003 server to a Win 2008 R2 server.  I'm running a classic ASP application.  In the 2003 server the following code worked for creating a file:

CONST SCRATCH_DIR = "E:\Temp\"
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set TFL = FSO.CreateTextFile(SCRATCH_DIR & "Debug.txt", True)

On the NEW server the Set TFL line gives me this error:

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046'
    Permission denied
    /inc/vbutil.inc, line 110

If I remove the Drive designation "E:\" from the CONST, the procedure works just fine; (except it writes to the C:\ drive) so I'm sure the error message is correct.

Could anyone please point me at where/how I'd change permissions for this (E:\Temp) directory?

Thanks very much in advance,

*(A dumb application programmer;)*

Answer (score 1):

You can change permissions on the folder by right clicking it > Properties > Security > Advanced.
Uncheck "Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent". 
Click "Add"
Modify permissions for the user running the script. They will need read, write and create permissions.